# Non-Indentation of only C++ comments in C++ mode

Tags: indentation, c++, comment

How can I configure my ~/.emacs so as to get the following effect?  In C++ mode, I want C++ comments (but not C-style comments), to always be unindented, i.e., the double slashes should always be first in a line, not preceded by whitespace.  By default, the Emacs C++ mode will indent C++ comments in the same way as it would any single-line statement.  I.e., I want code to look like:

```cpp
int main() {
        /* x is the number of foos */
        int x = 1; 
//      int x = 2;
        if (x == y) {
                 /* a is the number of bars */
                 int a = x;
//               int a = 2 * x;
        }
}
```

Note that C-style comments should still be indented normally.

Background:  I have a C++ codebase in which all "normal" comments are in C-style, and C++ comments are only used to comment out code.  This means that I can search for the string "//" within the cleanup to remove all such comments before I commit my code to SVN.  When commenting out code using C++ comments, the default behavior of Emacs makes it harder to see the old (commented-out) and new code side by side.  I.e., Emacs would give this:

```cpp
int main() {
        /* x is the number of foos */
        int x = 1; 
        //      int x = 2;
        if (x == y) { 
                 /* a is the number of bars */
                 int a = x;
                 //               int a = 2 * x;
        }
}
```

Note also that C++ comments that follow code on a line should not be affected.

Comment: What commands do you use currently that result in the comments appearing as in the second listing?  It's really hard to answer this without knowing how you're adding the comments.

Comment: When I add // to the beginning of a line, the line gets automatically indented.  I.e., the line is a normal non-comment line, I put the cursor at the beginning of that line (column 0), and enter //.  Then the line gets automatically indented.